# node-red retreive JSON or CSV feed into InfluxDB

Tags: javascript, json, csv, node-red

Versions

- Node-RED v0.16.2
- InfluxDB v1.2.2
- Grafana v4.2.0
- Ubuntu 16.04.2

I want to retrieve some weather observations from my local official weather station. I can choose between [csv](http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDV60801/IDV60801.94870.axf) & [JSON](http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDV60801/IDV60801.94870.json)

- I'm trying to retrieve the JSON feed with Node-RED.
- I've used an HTTP request node which returns a parsed JSON object

It returns this nested array:

**object**

- **observations:** *object*

  - **notice:** *array[1]*
  - **0:** *object*

    - **copyright:** "Copyright Commonwealth of Australia 2017, Bureau of Meteorology. For more information see: urlhere urlhere"
    - **copyright_url:** "urlhere"
    - **disclaimer_url:** "urlhere"
    - **feedback_url:** "urlhere"
  - **header:** *array[1]*
  - **0:** *object*

    - **refresh_message:** "Issued at 9:32 pm EST Tuesday 2 May 2017"
    - **ID:** "IDV60801"
    - **main_ID:** "IDV60800"
    - **name:** "Moorabbin Airport"
    - **state_time_zone:** "VIC"
    - **time_zone:** "EST"
    - **product_name:** "Weather Observations"
    - **state:** "Victoria"
  - **data:** *array[155]*
  - **[0 … 9]**

    - **0:** *object*
    - **sort_order:** 0
    - **wmo:** 94870
    - **name:** "Moorabbin Airport"
    - **history_product:** "IDV60801"
    - **local_date_time:** "02/09:30pm"
    - **local_date_time_full:** "20170502213000"
    - **aifstime_utc:** "20170502113000"
    - **lat:** -38
    - **lon:** 145.1
    - **apparent_t:** 5.4
    - **cloud:** "-"
    - **cloud_base_m:** null
    - **cloud_oktas:** null
    - **cloud_type:** "-"
    - **cloud_type_id:** null
    - **delta_t:** 2.5
    - **gust_kmh:** 19
    - **gust_kt:** 10
    - **air_temp:** 9
    - **dewpt:** 3.2
    - **press:** 1025.8
    - **press_msl:** 1025.8
    - **press_qnh:** 1025.8
    - **press_tend:** "-"
    - **rain_trace:** "1.0"
    - **rel_hum:** 67
    - **sea_state:** "-"
    - **swell_dir_worded:** "-"
    - **swell_height:** null
    - **swell_period:** null
    - **vis_km:** "10"
    - **weather:** "-"
    - **wind_dir:** "ESE"
    - **wind_spd_kmh:** 11
    - *wind_spd_kt:** 6

I only wanted the **data:** array so I used a function node "Extract Value" with this code:

`msg.payload = msg.payload.observations.data[0]
return msg;`

The above function returned this object:

- **sort_order:** 0
- **wmo:** 94870
- **name:** "Moorabbin Airport"
- **history_product:** "IDV60801"
- **local_date_time:** "02/09:30pm"
- **local_date_time_full:** "20170502213000"
- **aifstime_utc:** "20170502113000"
- **lat:** -38
- **lon:** 145.1
- **apparent_t:** 5.4
- **cloud:** "-"
- **cloud_base_m:** null
- **cloud_oktas:** null
- **cloud_type:** "-"
- **cloud_type_id:** null
- **delta_t:** 2.5
- **gust_kmh:** 19
- **gust_kt:** 10
- **air_temp:** 9
- **dewpt:** 3.2
- **press:** 1025.8
- **press_msl:** 1025.8
- **press_qnh:** 1025.8
- **press_tend:** "-"
- **rain_trace:** "1.0"
- **rel_hum:** 67
- **sea_state:** "-"
- **swell_dir_worded:** "-"
- **swell_height:** null
- **swell_period:** null
- **vis_km:** "10"
- **weather:** "-"
- **wind_dir:** "ESE"
- **wind_spd_kmh:** 11
- **wind_spd_kt:** 6

If I put this into InfluxDB via a storage node I receive this error:

> Error: A 400 Bad Request error occurred: {"error":"unable to parse 'bom-obs-moorabbin-airport aifstime_utc=\"20170513070000\",air_temp=13.6,apparent_t=10.6,cloud=\"-\",cloud_base_m=null,cloud_oktas=null,cloud_type=\"-\",cloud_type_id=null,delta_t=2.9,dewpt=7.6,gust_kmh=17,gust_kt=9,history_product=\"IDV60801\",lat=-38,local_date_time=\"13/05:00pm\",local_date_time_full=\"20170513170000\",lon=145.1,name=\"Moorabbin Airport\",press=1023.5,press_msl=1023.5,press_qnh=1023.5,press_tend=\"-\",rain_trace=\"0.0\",rel_hum=67,sea_state=\"-\",sort_order=0,swell_dir_worded=\"-\",swell_height=null,swell_period=null,vis_km=\"10\",weather=\"-\",wind_dir=\"SSW\",wind_spd_kmh=13,wind_spd_kt=7,wmo=94870': invalid number"}

If instead I insert a JSON node between the "Extract Value" & the InfluxDB storage node, this is the debug output I get:

> "{"sort_order":0,"wmo":94870,"name":"Moorabbin Airport","history_product":"IDV60801","local_date_time":"13/05:00pm","local_date_time_full":"20170513170000","aifstime_utc":"20170513070000","lat":-38,"lon":145.1,"apparent_t":10.6,"cloud":"-","cloud_base_m":null,"cloud_oktas":null,"cloud_type":"-","cloud_type_id":null,"delta_t":2.9,"gust_kmh":17,"gust_kt":9,"air_temp":13.6,"dewpt":7.6,"press":1023.5,"press_msl":1023.5,"press_qnh":1023.5,"press_tend":"-","rain_trace":"0.0","rel_hum":67,"sea_state":"-","swell_dir_worded":"-","swell_height":null,"swell_period":null,"vis_km":"10","weather":"-","wind_dir":"SSW","wind_spd_kmh":13,"wind_spd_kt":7}"

When I attach that JSON node to the InfluxDB storage node, there are no errors thrown, but there are no values in InfluxDB that I can view, graph or tabulate in Grafana.

What is the best way to take the above feed from that website and get it into InfluxDB so I can view it graphically in Grafana?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
return {
  payload: {
    data : msg.payload.observations.data[0]
  }
};
```

Comment: This error was returned by the InfluxDB node "Error: A 400 Bad Request error occurred: {"error":"unable to parse 'bom-obs-moorabbin-airport data=[object Object]': invalid boolean"}"

Comment: What is your JSON source?